# Error when validate entity with custom validation constraint

Tags: validation, symfony, dependency-injection, constraints

i get this error when  apply validate method on my controller.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to att\Bundle\Validator\Constraint\CertWfCheckValidator::validate() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint, none given, called in /var/www/html/att/src/att/Bundle/Controller/CertificateController.php on line 451 and defined

This my service definition:

```
    att.validator.certificate.wkcheck:
    class: att\Bundle\Validator\Constraint\CertWfCheckValidator
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@service_container"]
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator.certwkcheck }
```

Constraint Class:

```
namespace att\Bundle\Validator\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;


/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CertWfCheck extends Constraint {

public $message = "El certificado tiene un Tramite asociado, no se puede eliminar";



public function validatedBy() {
    return 'validator.certwkcheck';
}

public function getTargets() {
    return [self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT];
}
}
```

Validator class:

```
namespace att\Bundle\Validator\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CertWfCheckValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

    protected $em;
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container) {

        $this->em = $em;
        $this->container = $container;

    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        var_dump($value);
    }  
}
```

Controoller

```
   $certificate = $this->get('certificate.manager')
                    ->getCertificateById(
                            $this->getRequest()->request->get('id')
                            );

   $validator = $this->get('att.validator.certificate.wkcheck'); 
   $errors = $validator->validate($certificate);
   $errorsString = (string) $errors;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: I found the solution calling validation service.**

```
$constraint = new \att\Bundle\Validator\Constraint\CertWfCheck;
$errors = $this->container->get('validator')
                ->validateValue(
                        $entity,
                        $constraint);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. don't return array in method getTargets() in Constraint class, make it `return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;`

2 and the main.
Look at your Validator class, you define method "validate" with two arguments, but when you call this method you only provide one argument - $value. so you should initialize you constraint class and pass as a second argument to method. like this:

```
$certificate = $this->get('certificate.manager')
                    ->getCertificateById(
                            $this->getRequest()->request->get('id')
                            );

$validator = $this->get('att.validator.certificate.wkcheck');  
$constraint = new CertWfCheck();  
$errors = $validator->validate($certificate, $constraint);  
$errorsString = (string) $errors;
```

Comment: Thanks danis.  I can fix it calling validation service. I updated the answer.